# What would you do to measure wind speed below 50m?

Tags: electric-current, velocity, atmospheric-science, ionization-energy

Is there a radiation spectrum that could be used near the surface of the earth to fluoresce air enough to see the currents? Is there a complimentary CCD that can image that spectrum?

I am looking for a way to detect the wind direction and speed below 50m, does any physics guru have any ideas?

I know scintillation has worked above 250m  but if there is another way that would be useful.

Comment: There are plenty of things that would work... but why did you have to pick one with the least chances of success, instead of asking "What would you do to measure wind speed below 50m?".

Comment: Ok how's that? Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: Yes, I do have a few suggestions. The first one is that you describe properly what you really want to do.

Comment: Detect the motion of air above my head. In sunlight. During the day.

Comment: Here are the three ideas I came up with:

Comment: Scintillation of ions and detecting shift

Comment: Bragg Effect with RF radiation

Comment: Passive IR detection.

Comment: Custom microbolometer.

Comment: that's 4 ideas. But I know I don't know everything. What have I missed?

Comment: Wow... that's a lot of very tough to implement physical effects. What's wrong with the usual methods?

Answer (score 1):

Laser Doppler velocimetry can be used. Generally it is used to measure velocity of this range for any transparent fluid flow.

Comment: What happens if there are no particulates to back scatter from?

Comment: Or, would natural dust in the air be detectable?